# ValueError: time data '00:34 am' does not match format '%I:%M %p' : iam getting this error while adding 1 hour to the zero hours time

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add_one_hour(time_str):
    # Convert the time string to a datetime object
    dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%I:%M %p")

    # Add one hour to the datetime object
    dt += timedelta(hours=1)

    # Format the modified datetime object back to a time string
    modified_time_str = dt.strftime("%I:%M %p")
    return modified_time_str

original_time_str = '00:34 am'
modified_time_str = add_one_hour(original_time_str)
print(modified_time_str )
```

raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '00:34 am' does not match format '%I:%M %p'

Comment: `%I` is for 12-hour time, values go from 01 to 12. So 00 is not valid.

Comment: Hour in 24-hour time is `%H`.